# optimizers in deep learning

Tags: neural-networks, python, terminology

I'm new to the deep learning field and I've a question that I didn't get for it a clear answer or explanation in the course, I understand the tensors and the idea behind batches but I don't really get the concept of an optimizer like **adam optimizer** . why we are using them and for what , where is the purpose .

By the way I'm learning pytorch.